# How to change the main activity shown on the emulator to another activity?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest, android-activity

I am having a problem with setting the main activity that is supposed to be shown on the emulator. Initially I already have an main activity (my first page) that will be shown when I first start up my emulator. 
 But then now I wish to change the first activity that will be shown first when I run my application. I have changed the name of the activity in my android manifest however the first activity that runs is my previous activity instead of the new one that I have created. I have no idea why the new activity won't show although I have changed the android manifest 
 Anyone has an idea on solving my problem? Thanks in advance. 
 Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the activity which you want to be launched initially with the intent filter in your Android Manifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name=".newActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".FirstAvtivity" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Android Studio `Run -> Edits Configuration` menu, you can change the Launch activity manually.